# Как решить проблему с настройкой RAID массива?

Tags: железо, raid

Установили мне на Хэтзнэре сервер. Для моего [RAID контроллера](https://storage.microsemi.com/en-us/support/raid/sas_raid/asr-8405/). можно дополнительно заказать [систему кэширования](http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/afm700_iug_4_2016.pdf).
Стоит ли морочить голову с доукомплектацией выделенного сервера? В моём случае, когда если установлены SSD (для дата-центра) и настроена система мониторинга SMART.

Comment: Это не система кеширования, а дополнительная батарейка для контроллера. Позволит не потерять данные которые были в кэше контроллера в случае внезапного обрыва питания. Нужно оно вам или нет решать только Вам.

Comment: @ВикторПупкин а Вы ставите себе такие батарейки. Я так понимаю их отдельно продают. Мой хостер хочет за них отдельно 12$/месяц

Comment: А если сейчас кэш в контроллере не активирован у меня сейчас.

Comment: на hetzner не ставлю, там лучше за самими дисками следить, часто вылетают, а вот чтоб питание падало не помню такого

Comment: кэш там не активирован по причине отсутствия батарейки, влючить можно просто он ругнется что нет батарейки.